# TestFlight & iOS strange error while trying to send out test release

Tags: ios, testflight

My Testflight environment i use for iOS crashed on me. I registered with a new account, created a new development provisioning profile in provisioning profiles, reinstalled testflight on my iPad, basically i did everything from scratch again. 
It seemed to be working, testflight recognized my device and i was able to send out a new test app, but when i pressed the submit button, this strange screen appears saying

> nonetype object has no attribute keys

.[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance, Zoli

Comment: Testflight application never worked for me. Are you able to upload your build via Tesflight website?

Comment: Yes. Also I deleted the testflight app and installed it again then it works fine.

Comment: Would you suggest it in an answer, so i don't have to give the points for the accepted answer myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and sent a report to TestFlight support team.

But after I updated TestFlight App to the latest version now, it seems working fine.

Additional Info:

I got answer from TestFlight Support.

> Sorry you are experiencing trouble.
>
> To help troubleshoot this, please provide us with the following
>   information:
>
> - The .txt log (in the desktop app go to Help > Show Log in Finder)
> - The .IPA you are attempting to upload
> - The version of the desktop app you're using

Comment: I also faced the same issue and reinstalled testflight desktop app. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your testflight desktop app and try a new download/installation

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling it seems to work... or try updating it...